# Scalar-valued function doesn't return expected result

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have created a scalar-valued function in Microsoft SSMS, it is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetCurrentBalFromName] 
(
    @Name NVarchar,
    @CliFl Bit
)
RETURNS Money
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentBal Money

    select @CurrentBal=SUM(tt.Debt) from  
     (select case t.Clientfl when 1 then dbo.fGetClientNameFromId(t.AgentID) 
                    else dbo.fGetSupplierNameFromId(t.AgentID) 
             end as Cli,
             t.Clientfl,
         case t.Clientfl when 1 then 
            case t.Incomfl 
                when 1 then t.Amount 
                       else (-1)*t.Amount 
            end
         else
            case t.Incomfl
                when 1 then (-1)*t.Amount
                        else t.Amount
            end
         end as Debt              
      from [Store].[dbo].[Money] t) tt where tt.Cli=@Name and tt.Clientfl=@CliFl
      group by tt.Cli

    RETURN @CurrentBal

END
```

When I execute

```
Select dbo.fGetCurrentBalFromName('Вали',1)
```

I get no(NULL) result.

But when I try to execute the query alone without parameters

```
select SUM(tt.Debt) from  
         (select case t.Clientfl when 1 then dbo.fGetClientNameFromId(t.AgentID) 
                        else dbo.fGetSupplierNameFromId(t.AgentID) 
                 end as Cli,
                 t.Clientfl,
             case t.Clientfl when 1 then 
                case t.Incomfl 
                    when 1 then t.Amount 
                           else (-1)*t.Amount 
                end
             else
                case t.Incomfl
                    when 1 then (-1)*t.Amount
                            else t.Amount
                end
             end as Debt              
          from [Store].[dbo].[Money] t) tt where tt.Cli='Вали' and tt.Clientfl=1
          group by tt.Cli
```

I get exactly what I want. 
 So what is the mistake I had done creating the scalar-valued function. 
 Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the parameter `@Name`.

```
@Name NVarchar
```

Without size it defaults to 1 character.

Try something like this.

```
@Name NVarchar(100)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03af7/1/0)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think I could make such a silly mistake.